# Accessing Fletcher-32 checksum in HDF5 file

Tags: hdf5, h5py

Suppose I want to check that a particular H5 file is the one I think it is, and hasn't had some dataset altered while I wasn't looking.  I've already turned on the Fletcher-32 filter.  I'm wondering if there's some way to *access the checksum* stored in the H5 file.

To be clear, I don't want to recalculate the checksum, I'm assuming that the data is consistent with the checksum, and I'm not expecting anything nefarious; I just want a quick way to peek in and make a list of the checksums — then peek in later to make sure my list hasn't somehow gotten out of sync with the data.  Ideally, I'd like to do this through the `h5py` interface, but the C interface would at least give me somewhere to start.

My use case is basically this: I have a database of my H5 files, and I want to be sure that none of the *datasets* have changed without the database knowing about it.  I don’t care if — say — an attribute has been changed or added, which means file sizes, modification times, and MD5 sums are of no use.  For example, I might realize that some scaling was off by a factor of 2, go in and change those bits in one dataset without changing the dataset's shape or even the number of bytes in the file — but then fail to update the database for one reason or another. I need to be able to detect such a change.  And since Fletcher-32 is already being computed by HDF5 with every change to our data, it would be very convenient.

Basically, I'm just asking for the highest-level API calls that can achieve this.

---

I've found one place in the HDF5 source code [here](https://github.com/live-clones/hdf5/blob/f0d22e54c705285b10f8192be6b26ba1a7ae3fbc/src/H5Zfletcher32.c#L95-L98) where it reads the stored checksum — evidently the [last 4 bytes](https://github.com/live-clones/hdf5/blob/f0d22e54c705285b10f8192be6b26ba1a7ae3fbc/src/H5Zfletcher32.c#L44) of the buffer.

Using this fact, it looks like there is *an* answer, as of HDF5 1.10.2 and [h5py 2.10](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/pull/1190).  But it's still not nearly as fast as I'd like — presumably because it's reading all the bytes in every chunk, possibly exacerbated by the need to be constantly allocating new buffers for all those reads.

Essentially, we want to bypass any filters (compression, etc.), read the last 4 bytes of the raw data chunk, and interpret them as an unsigned 32-bit integer.  The `read_direct_chunk` in `h5py` was added in v 2.10, and corresponds to the HDF5 function `H5D_READ_CHUNK`.

Here's some simple example code, assuming `test.h5` has a 2-dimensional dataset named `data`.

```py
import numpy as np
import h5py

with h5py.File('test.h5', 'r') as f:
    ds = f['data']
    n_chunks_0 = int(np.ceil(ds.shape[0] / ds.chunks[0]))
    n_chunks_1 = int(np.ceil(ds.shape[1] / ds.chunks[1]))
    checksums = np.empty((n_chunks_0, n_chunks_1), dtype=np.uint32)
    for i in range(n_chunks_0):
        for j in range(n_chunks_1):
            filter_mask, raw_data_bytes = d.id.read_direct_chunk((i, j))
            checksums[i, j] = np.frombuffer(raw_data_bytes[-4:], dtype=np.uint32)[0]
```

Note that there *may* be some issues with endianness that I'm not considering.

Anyway, the question remains: Is there any nice API for getting just those last 4 bits, rather than the whole chunk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very new interface that lets me do exactly what I want.  It was introduced in [HDF5 v1.10.5](https://www.hdfgroup.org/2019/02/hdf5-1-10-5-release-newsletter-168/) and [will be in h5py 3.0](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/pull/1200) — specifically, the (H5D)get_num_chunks and (H5D)get_chunk_info functions.

Here's a simple example showing how to use these functions to get the checksums for *every* chunk in the `data` dataset of `test.h5`.  Note that we need both h5py capabilities and seek/read capabilities — which is why I used this weird way of opening the file.

```py
import numpy as np
import h5py

with open('test.h5', 'rb') as stream:
    with h5py.File(stream, 'r') as f:
        ds = f['data']
        assert ds.fletcher32, ('Dataset does not have Fletcher-32 checksums')
        checksums = np.zeros((ds.id.get_num_chunks(),), dtype=np.uint32)
        for i in range(checksums.size):
            chunk_info = ds.id.get_chunk_info(i)
            offset = chunk_info.byte_offset + chunk_info.size - 4
            stream.seek(offset, 0)
            checksums[i] = np.frombuffer(stream.read(4), dtype=np.uint32)[0]
```

This code works with the current master branch of h5py.  The results agree with those from the code I added to my question above.  But other than the chunk info, this code only reads exactly 4 bytes per chunk, and is thus probably about as efficient as it can be.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies in advance; this is an incomplete answer based on info I can find. From my read of HDF5, h5py and PyTables docs, you can't access the checksum value directly (with Python or any other language).
This is my understanding of HDF5 checksum behavior:

- Data is checksummed when written.
- The checksum is calculated and stored for each dataset chunk.
- The dataset is checked for corruption when you read the dataset (chunk).
- The chunk's saved checksum is compared to the value calculated when you read it.

Given this limitation, I don't see how you can do what you propose.

That said, there is a way to peek at the data and verify integrity before you operate on the data. See code below. It creates a file with 4 datasets: 2 have `fletcher32=True`, the other 2 do not. It then uses `visititems()` to recursively visit each node in the file (calling `def check_fletcher`). The called routine checks if the node is a dataset and `fletcher32=True`. If true, it attempts to read the dataset. If the read fails, it will issue an error (that you can trap). Unfortunately, I don't know how to corrupt a dataset to test the `except:` part of the code. Maybe this will give you some ideas.

```
import numpy as np
import h5py

def check_fletcher(name, node):
    if isinstance(node, h5py.Dataset) and node.fletcher32:
       print (name,': ', end = '')
       try:
           test = node[:]
           print ('test successful')
       except:
           print ('test failed')

##################################    
data = np.random.rand(20, 20, 20)

with h5py.File('SO_62946682.h5','w') as h5f:

    group = h5f.create_group('data')
    
    ds1 = group.create_dataset('/data1/test1', data=data, fletcher32=True)
    print (ds1.name, ':', ds1.fletcher32)
   
    ds2 = group.create_dataset('/data2/test2', data=data)
    print (ds2.name, ':', ds2.fletcher32)

    ds3 = group.create_dataset('/data3/test3', data=data, fletcher32=True)
    print (ds3.name, ':', ds3.fletcher32)

    ds4 = group.create_dataset('/data4/test4', data=data)
    print (ds4.name, ':', ds4.fletcher32)

    h5f.visititems(check_fletcher)
```

Comment: Thanks.  Maybe I didn't explain myself well.  I agree with your understanding of HDF5 checksum behavior.  But I actually don't even care about data integrity.  My point is that those checksum bytes are stored on the disk, and I want to read them — once when I create the file, and then periodically again to make sure they haven't changed.  I've explained this a bit more in my question.

Comment: You asked: "_Is there any nice API for getting just those last 4 bits?_" If there's an API, I can't find it. The code you added to your question might be the best (only) answer. It's a nice work.